# Floors and ceilings

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose that $ n $ is an integer, and $ x $ is a real number, and $ x \ne n $. If $ \lfloor x \rfloor = n $, what are $ \lfloor −x \rfloor $ and $ \lceil −x \rceil $ (express them in terms of $ n $)?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi and welcome to math.SE. Please use [MathJax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/570189) to improve readability and increase your chances to get meaningful answers.
Also you're more likely to be well received if you show us your efforts and attempts, instead of merely stating your question.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, $ x \ne n $ and $ \lfloor x \rfloor = n $, which means that $ x $ is somewhere between $ n $ and $ n + 1 $. This means that $ -x $ is somewhere between $ -n $ and $ -n - 1 $.